# Can this be made into a sql join

Tags: sql, join

I want to find where mydata has a Q value but not at least one corresponding d value. How would I solve using a left join or right join?

If it can not be solved using joins, please give some insight into why not, because I am not seeing it.

Below is the solution that I found which works against data provided.

```
SELECT distinct tablea.mykey 
FROM mytest as tablea
where tablea.mydata = 'Q'
  and tablea.mykey not in (select distinct tableb.mykey 
                           FROM mytest as tableb
                           where tableb.mydata = 'd')
```

```
mykey   mydata
7   d
5   Q
5   d
5   d
6   Q
6   d
6   a
9   Q
9   a
9   a
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `distinct` in the sub-query is useless

Comment: Might help performance anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an outer join and then select only the non-matches

```
SELECT distinct tablea.mykey 
FROM   mytest as a
left join mytest as b on a.mykey = b.mykey
                      and b.mydata = 'd'
where  a.mydata = 'Q'
and    b.mykey is null
```

Comment: What of the d value?

Comment: Updated answer to include d

Comment: `left join mytest as b on a.mykey = b.mykey
                      and b.mydata = 'd'`

Comment: From another question ... When making OUTER JOINs (ANSI-89 or ANSI-92), filtration location matters because criteria specified in the ON clause is applied before the JOIN is made. Criteria against an OUTER JOINed table provided in the WHERE clause is applied after the JOIN is made.